# bcrypt number of possibile password combination

Tags: security, passwords, bcrypt

I'm trying to understand how bcrypt works under the hood. For example, if i create a hash a password, for example "hello", i receive:

```
$2y$12$wsoPmf7KXqGPWke9io0YbOf2Vln61awWwpCS./kGH5.rVE8Trbc6q
```

So, every time i hash another "hello", i receive another crypt password, i think the number of possible password combination in bcrypt depend to the number of round, for example 12 (in my case).

With a round of 12, how many combination of "hello" exist exactly? And how i can calculate that?

Comment: First, learn the [internals](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/33696/18298)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bcrypt includes a 128-bit (16 byte) salt, encoded in modular crypt format as the first 22 characters of the hash. In your example, the salt is `wsoPmf7KXqGPWke9io0YbO`.

There is a different password -> hash for each salt, so there are 2^128 or approximately 10^38 possible hashes per password for a given cost parameter. If you change the cost parameter, that will generate a different set of 10^38 possible hashes (but the size of the cost parameter doesn't increase or decrease the number of possible hashes).